# external swf should unload when reaches final frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external

I have a swf file loaded into a main movie. When the child is finished playing, ie reaches its final frame, I would like the swf to unload. Can anyone tell me what bits I can add to this code?

```
//start button

start_button_aboriginal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3,false,0,true);

import fl.display.ProLoader;
var fl_ProLoader_3:ProLoader;

var fl_ToLoad_3:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
//ADDED APR02 START
    fl_ProLoader_3.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, childInitHandler);
    fl_ProLoader_3.load(new URLRequest("myths/myth_aboriginal.swf"));
//ADDED APR02 END

if(fl_ToLoad_3)
{
    fl_ProLoader_3 = new ProLoader();
    fl_ProLoader_3.load(new URLRequest("myths/myth_aboriginal.swf"));
    addChild(fl_ProLoader_3);
    fl_ProLoader_3.x = 114;
    fl_ProLoader_3.y = 41;
}
else
{
removeChild(fl_ProLoader_3);
fl_ProLoader_3.unloadAndStop();
fl_ProLoader_3 = null;
}
// Toggle whether you want to load or unload the SWF
fl_ToLoad_3 = !fl_ToLoad_3;

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could

1) Use the undocumented addFrameScript function defined in the MovieClip class to place a callback on the last frame of the child SWF. Useful if you don't have control over the code in your loaded SWF.

addFrameScript() has the following signature:

```
addFrameScript(frameNumber, callback); //frameNumber is zero-based (unlike in the Flash authoring suite, here you would enter 0 to refer to the first frame, and 1 for the second.)
```

In the parent SWF, add the following:

```
function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ...
    fl_ProLoader_3.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, childInitHandler);
    fl_ProLoader_3.load(new URLRequest("myths/myth_aboriginal.swf"));
    ...
}

function childInitHandler(event:Event):void {
    MovieClip(fl_ProLoader_3.content).addFrameScript(MovieClip(fl_ProLoader_3.content).totalFrames-1, unloadChild);
}

function unloadChild() {
    fl_ProLoader_3.unloadAndStop();
}
```

If you're worried about addFrameScript going away - don't be. When you put code on the timeline, all that code is actually compiled into functions in the document class, with frame listeners added via addFrameScript.

Remember to define function *unloadChild()*.

```
function unloadChild():void {
    fl_ProLoader_3.unloadAndStop();
}
```

-OR-

2) Dispatch an event from your loaded SWF when it reaches the final frame.

In last frame of child SWF:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new Event("lastFrameReached"));
```

In parent SWF, add the following:

```
fl_ProLoader_3.content.addEventListener("lastFrameReached", unloadChild);
```

-OR-

3) Subscribe to the ENTER_FRAME event of the child and check if the child is on its last frame.

In parent SWF, add the following:

```
fl_ProLoader_3.content.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkIfEnded);

function checkIfEnded(event:Event):void {
    if (fl_ProLoader_3.content.currentFrame == fl_ProLoader_3.content.totalFrames) {
        unloadChild();
    }
}
```

I personally prefer addFrameScript - seems to me a cleaner solution. Callback runs once, you don't have to poll and you don't need to modify the child SWF.

Comment: +1 for answer #2. This is the best way to do it, and is what my answer would have been as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can't have any code in the child swf, since the film is for iOS. So I will give the first one a try.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm getting some errors here. Can you tell me, WHERE exactly these bits of code would go? Many thanks,

Comment: @fiona, for #1, all the code belongs in the parent SWF that is doing the loading. Could you elaborate on the errors that you are getting? I'll also edit the example to make it a little clearer.

Comment: thank you - here are the errors I am getting for that bit of code, I am getting two of these: 

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 69 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before tripledot.

Comment: and I am using option nr one. Your two parts of code I have added just after this bit:

import fl.display.ProLoader;
var fl_ProLoader_3:ProLoader;

Comment: Still can't get it right - it is giving me trouble with the tripledot. This is the last piece of code I need before launch, so it would be GREAT if I can just wrap this up! Thanks.

Comment: I have just edited my initial code, above. The current errors I am getting are "1120: Access of undefined property callback"

Comment: Get rid of this line:
addFrameScript("Scene 3", 845, callback);

and leave out the three dots. I meant the "..." as your own code above and below the code snippet.

Comment: You should revert to your original code, and just add the code snippet under "In the parent SWF, add the following:" into your function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3(event:MouseEvent). Don't include the triple dots. Don't replace your original code, just add those two lines in. At present you've removed the addChild() which I recall was present in the original code, so it won't even display.

Comment: Hello Raymond - you are a hero for staying with me on this and being so patient; Action Script is a tricky one! I have edited the complete code now; do I need anything else? Don't I need to remove the "if-else" statement now, as I am calling it twice? I don't need the toggle load/unload with that start button. Only load. I have another button to unload it. I just need the start button to start it and then when it's all done, the swf just automatically unloads itself.

Comment: I have this error now: 
"Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 60, Line 71 1120: Access of undefined property childInitHandler." Any advice??

Comment: If you attempt to understand the error you would easily see where things are going wrong - you need to have the function childInitHandler present in your code because you are referencing the function. The error "access of undefined property" indicates that you have referenced a function but have not defined the function in your code. In this case, put in the functions that you're missing. function childInitHandler(event:Event)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to solve this, and it has been asked many times...

- [Unload child swf on last frame of child swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115373/unload-child-swf-on-last-frame-of-child-swf)
- [When External SWF has reached Frame X, how do I unload it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668630/when-external-swf-has-reached-frame-x-how-do-i-unload-it?rq=1)

That said, one way you could resolve this without creating event listeners on the child swf, is by periodically checking the child swf for the current frame.  If it's the last one on the swf, call the unload method.

```
// once every second, indefinitely.
var tick:Timer = new Timer(1000, 0);
tick.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, checkSWF);
tick.start();

//Load something to the stage.
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("child.swf")); 
addChild(loader);


function checkSWF(e:Event):void {
    if (loader.content.currentFrame == loader.content.totalFrames) {
        tick.stop(); // stop the timer
        loader.unloadAndStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a timer seems highly inefficient and inaccurate. Why not run the check on `ENTER_FRAME` for the child SWF?

Comment: The timer is a simple solution.  ENTER_FRAME is valid, but if you don't want to check on every interval, you'd need to limit it with http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer(), which is essentially what timer does.

Comment: thanks so much for the fast reply! Tell me, where does this code belong? On the frame in the parent movie, I assume, but at the end of the code? At the beginning?

Comment: also, would I skip the second portion of code, since I am already loading a URLrequest, just stick with portions 1 and 3?